# Ben 10 omnitrix animation

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

So i have modelled the omnitrix, and now i want to animate it. I am very new to animation. I wanted to know, ho to achieve the effect as in the two images 3 and 4. When the two pieces approach each other, i want their intersection to disappear. 
 How can i achieve such effect? Any help or suggestion is appreaciated. Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the result i want to achieve with my mesh! When the two pieces approach their intersection should disappear and the mesh underneath should be visible!

[image]

Comment: This isn't difficult for Blender.  I tried it and used a rotoscoped mask for the overlapping center surfaces.  It visually cuts through the sliding planes but not the green meshed interior. Am on an online PC at the mo. More details if required.  The only difficulty for you might be the render.  For speed and convenience I rendered with OpenGL on version 2.77.  Masking is a lot easier and discriminatory with that.  If you're using nodes/compositor, etc, it would require more work.

Comment: Further to the above - A lossless alpha layered video could be rendered and that used to texture a plane in your model's casing.  That would bring together the  different rendering methods and keep your preferred shading.